# C++ Aws S3 IOStream Gets destroyed when passing it around. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, c++11, amazon-s3, iostream

So my getObject function looks somthing like is:

```
    Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client;
    Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request;
    object_request.SetBucket(bucket_name);
    object_request.SetKey(object_name);

    // Get the object
    auto get_object_outcome = s3_client.GetObject(object_request);

    // Get an Aws::IOStream reference to the retrieved file
    auto &retrieved_file = get_object_outcome.GetResultWithOwnership().GetBody();

    return retrieved_file
```

The retrieved_file is an AWS::IOStream, but the data in the stream is lost after the calling function gets this object back.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: return `get_object_outcome` I think, it owns the stream

Comment: I am ultra suspicious about `auto &retrieved_file = get_object_outcome.GetResultWithOwnership().GetBody();` I have a hinch that you end up with a dangling reference. Full disclosure - I know nothing about AWS and I might be completely wrong.

Comment: There are details missing.  How do you know that`.GetResultWithOwnerShip()` returned anything meaningful?  You don't check, and you assume you can call `GetBody()` on this item.  I know function chaining looks "cool", but it only works if all the items on the chain are valid.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html  im following the the c++ sdk from AWS

Comment: You are not following the code at the link when it comes to error checking.  You assumed that all the functions didn't fail.  Where is the call to `IsSuccess()`?

Comment: All you've done is point out flaws in the code I posted instead of answering the question about the Aws::IOStream object. things about function chaining, and error handling is not my concern. Im not posting the full code here thats why i said my code looks "something" like this. Im asking about the Aws::IOStream

Comment: @BossHacker The comment section is for comments, not answers, so I commented.  That's how it works here.  Pointing out flaws in the code that *could* cause an issue is **exactly** why the comment section exists.  If the reason is known, then that would go in the answer section.